# Missing Month Name between two dates

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I am using this code

```
int unitFlags =  NSMonthCalendarUnit;   
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];    
int months = [comps month];
```

I want actually the name of the month which is missing any idea?

Comment: What u actully want to do? get January, February from int months or what?

Comment: Month name between two dates? If `startDate` is `2012-07-01` and `endDate` is `2012-09-01`, what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: i want missing months between two dates suppose dates are 23 jun 2012 , 23 Aug 2012 then missing month would be july.

Comment: What if `startDate` is `2012-07-01` and `endDate` is `2013-04-01`? What if `startDate` is `1994-07-01` and `endDate` is `2013-04-01`?

Comment: end date will be graeter than start date. if startdate is 1994-07-01 and end date is 2013-04-01 then name of all missing months but this much difference will be seen very rarely.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this question in two ways, I don't know which one is better : (I am expecting people to comment on my answers)

As you want all the months name between start and end date, you can do as:

**Method 1:**

```
NSString *startString=@"23 Jun 2012";
NSString *endString=@"23 Dec 2013";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterDDMMMYYYY=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatterDDMMMYYYY setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];

NSDate *startDate=[dateFormatterDDMMMYYYY dateFromString:startString];
NSDate *endDate=[dateFormatterDDMMMYYYY dateFromString:endString];

NSMutableArray *betweenMonths=[NSMutableArray new];
NSDate *tempDate=startDate;
while (tempDate<endDate) {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterMMM=[NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatterMMM setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
    NSString *monthName=[dateFormatterMMM stringFromDate:tempDate];
    [betweenMonths addObject:monthName];

    //tempDate is calculted after storing because you not need the last month.
    NSCalendar *calendar=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components=[NSDateComponents new];
    components.month=1;
    tempDate=[calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:tempDate options:0];
}
NSLog(@"Month Name : %@",betweenMonths);
```

**Method 2:**

```
NSString *startString=@"23 Jun 2012";
NSString *endString=@"23 Dec 2013";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterDDMMMYYYY=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatterDDMMMYYYY setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];

NSDate *startDate=[dateFormatterDDMMMYYYY dateFromString:startString];
NSDate *endDate=[dateFormatterDDMMMYYYY dateFromString:endString];

NSInteger month = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSMonthCalendarUnit
                                                   fromDate: startDate
                                                     toDate: endDate
                                                    options: 0] month];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterMMM=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatterMMM setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
NSString *startMonth=[dateFormatterMMM stringFromDate:startDate];

NSArray *months=@[@"Jan",@"Feb",@"Mar",@"Apr",@"May",@"Jun",@"Jul",@"Aug",@"Sep",@"Oct",@"Nov",@"Dec"];

NSInteger startDateMonth=[months indexOfObject:startMonth];

for (NSInteger i=startDateMonth+1; i<startDateMonth+month; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Moths : %@",months[i%12]); //%12 for checking if i goes beyond 11, as endDate may be more then one year span long

}
```

Comment: actually my start date is 1 Jan 2012 and end date is 13 Jan 2013. and answer comes out to be 11 using the above code how can i use this to get the names of month like Feb,Mar etc till Dec, start date and end date can vary

Comment: For simply finding month name, why to use components, use what i answered. isnot it so simple?

Comment: i can get the month name form a date but i want missing months between two dates suppose dates are 23 jun 2012 , 23 Aug 2012 then missing month would be july.